# How to find Shared Memory Limits and Semaphore Limits in Solaris,HP-UX and AIX?

Tags: solaris, aix, hp-ux

I'm using the following commands to find Shared Memory Limits and Semaphore Limits in Linux.

To find Shared Memory Limits I used this command:

```
ipcs -lm
```

and I got the following output:

```
------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 4194303
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 1073741824
min seg size (bytes) = 1
```

To find Semaphore Limits I used this command:

```
ipcs -ls
```

and I got the following output:

```
------ Semaphore Limits --------
max number of arrays = 128
max semaphores per array = 250
max semaphores system wide = 32000
max ops per semop call = 32
semaphore max value = 32767
```

I don't know how to get this output in Solaris,HP-UX and AIX. I have searched lot in internet but I couldn't get the fine solution. Share your ideas to get this thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you writing shell script or you need solution in C? Anyway, using sysctls in Linux may be easier: i.e. `cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax` will give you maximum shared memory segment. Speaking  of Solaris, Solaris 10 introduces projects, so solutions for >= 10 and <10 will be different. Either way, may be trial-and-error approach is easier: `if error in shmget(100 GB) than shmmax is not enough`

Comment: Yes I am writing shell script

Comment: I posted my knowledge about Linux & Solaris. I used to do that in AIX once, but there was long ago, so I made my post a wiki, hope someone will updates my post on AIX & HP-UX

Answer (score 2):

#### Trial and error

The simplest and more robust method is to probe if you can allocate these resources, i.e.:

```
int shmid = shmget(key, LARGE_BUFFER_SIZE, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
void* data = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

if (data == (char *)(-1)) {
    /* Log an error and exit */
}
```

I.e. Oracle Database does that.

#### Linux

On Linux these limits are handled via `sysctl`:

```
$ /usr/sbin/sysctl kernel.shmmax
kernel.shmmax = 18446744073709551615
$ /usr/sbin/sysctl kernel.sem
kernel.sem = 250        256000  32      1024
             ^ SEMMSL   ^ SEMMNI
```

You can get sysctl parameters from `/proc/sys`:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/sem
250     256000  32      1024
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
18446744073709551615
```

#### Solaris before 10

In Solaris before 10 kernel parameters were used. They are set in `/etc/system`. You can get actual values from kernel, but only when `shmsys` and `semsys` modules are loaded (Solaris lazy-loads them on first syscall):

```
# modload /kernel/sys/sparcv9/semsys
# modload /kernel/sys/sparcv9/shmsys
# echo 'shminfo_shmmax/J' | mdb -k
shminfo_shmmax:
shminfo_shmmax: 800000
# echo 'seminfo_semmni/J' | mdb -k
seminfo_semmni:
seminfo_semmni: a0000003c
```

Note that I used `/J` modifier in mdb which dumps 8-byte in hexademical. On 32-bits builds, you're probably will need `/X` which dumps 4-bytes.

#### Solaris 10 and later

Solaris 10 introduced projects, that allow to set these limits with granularity of user or even a process. Use `prctl` to get appropriate limits:

```
# prctl -n project.max-shm-memory $$
process: 3451: bash
NAME    PRIVILEGE       VALUE    FLAG   ACTION                       RECIPIENT
project.max-shm-memory
        privileged       474MB      -   deny                                 -
        system          16,0EB    max   deny                                 -
# prctl -n project.max-sem-ids $$
process: 3451: bash
NAME    PRIVILEGE       VALUE    FLAG   ACTION                       RECIPIENT
project.max-sem-ids
        privileged        128       -   deny                                 -
        system          16,8M     max   deny                                 -
# prctl -n process.max-sem-nsems $$
process: 3451: bash
NAME    PRIVILEGE       VALUE    FLAG   ACTION                       RECIPIENT
process.max-sem-nsems
        privileged        512       -   deny                                 -
        system          32,8K     max   deny                                 -
```

`priviliged` values is what you seek

Answer (score 0):

### AIX

AIX doesn't have any commands that will output the IPC limits that you're looking for, unfortunately.  *At least none that I've ever found...*     I generally refer to [this table](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/ipc_limits.htm?lang=en) and assume the lowest common denominator for the versions of AIX that I'm supporting.

If I was needing to programmatically detect limits in the shell, I'd just write a wrapper function/script that encapsulated the logic listed in the table, based on the detected version of AIX.